# replace two successive setTimeout with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

In an Angular application, we execute a method. And we need, after this method has been called, to trigger two other methods, spaced in time.

`Method call -> wait 150 ms ----> second action -> wait 300 ms -------- > third action`

I could set two nested `setTimeout`. It works but I find it ugly.

```js
public toggleSideContainer() {
    this.myLayoutService.toggleSideContainer();

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.mainContainer, 'side-container');

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.renderer.addClass(this.sideContainer, 'open');
        }, 300);
    }, 150);
}
```

What could be the proper rxjs operators/sequence to get this result in a proper rxjs way?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```js
Observable.of(true)
    .delay(150)
    .do(() => {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.mainContainer, 'side-container');
    })
    .delay(300)
    .do(() => {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.sideContainer, 'open');
    });
```

Or with the new lettable/pipeable operators:

```js
Observable.of(true).pipe(
    delay(150),
    tap(() => {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.mainContainer, 'side-container');
    }),
    delay(300),
    tap(() => {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.sideContainer, 'open');
    })
);
```

Source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot. What about testing it through jasmine `fakeAsync`, do we simply have to tick as we do with `setTimeout` and spy on `renderer` to have been called with proper arguments? Or is there any specific way to test that?

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy I'm not so familiar with Jasmine yet, but I think tick should work in this case too.

Comment: Don't forget to add the subscribe at the end of pipe arguments: `.pipe(...).subscribe()` if you want it to be executed! Because if nobody listen as subscriber nothing will be executed at all (basic RxJS lessons)

Comment: Tbh this approach doesn't look much more beautiful or elegant to me than the nested setTimeout in the question...

I wonder if this could be done better with the newest version of rxjs.

Answer (score 4):

I have put together a pen over at CodePen where you can see how to implement it using RxJS:
[Use RxJS instead of setTimeout](https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/XWjKWmQ)

```
const observablePattern = of(true)
.pipe(
    delay(100),
    tap(() => {
        log('After 100 ms');
        setSize(50);
    }),
    delay(1000),
    tap(() => {
        log('After another 1000 ms')
        setSize(150);
    }),
    delay(500),
    tap(() => {
        log('After another 500 ms');
        setSize(100);
    })
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2):

By using both the `do` operator and the `delay` operator, it should be pretty easy:

```js
someObservable.delay(150).do(
     () => this.renderer.addClass(this.mainContainer, 'side-container')
).delay(300).do(
     () => this.renderer.addClass(this.sideContainer, 'open')
);
```